# How to print author's email address in in node template

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have a content of type summary only visible by the author and administrators. I need to print in my node--summary.tpl.php the author's email address that was set at the account creation.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<?php
  print $user->mail;
?>
```

If `$user` is not available use

```
<?php
  $user = user_load($node->uid);
  print $user->mail;
?>
```

Comment: Such a simple answer. Thank you GiorgosK it works as expected.